# Spring get request file not being downloaded

Tags: angularjs, spring, download

I want to download a file when clicking on a button in my AngularJS app which runs on Tomcat with a Java Spring backend but nothing is happening. The method in the backend is called and everything seems to have worked....but **my browser doesn't download anything**.

What am I missing?

Here's the AngularJS code, which logs `Export-Response:[object Object]`:

```
exportProjects() {
    let filteredProjectIds = [];
    for (let i in this.filteredProjects) {
        for (let x = 0, l = this.filteredProjects[i].length; x < l; x++) {
            if (!this.isOldProjectsBundle(this.filteredProjects[i][x])) {
                filteredProjectIds.push(this.filteredProjects[i][x].id);
            }
        }
    }
    this.$http.get('/profiles/projectWordExport?filteredProjects=' + filteredProjectIds.join(",")).then(response => {
        console.log("Export-Response:" + response);
        return response;
    });
}
```

This is the Java code being called (it's really being called, already debugged it, no errors occuring):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projectWordExport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getProjectsWord(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String filteredProjects) throws Exception {
        //Load project objects from input string or load all projects if input empty
        List<Project> projects = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        if (filteredProjects.isEmpty()) {
            projects = projectRepository.findAll();
        } else {
            String[] pIds = filteredProjects.split(",");
            for (String pId : pIds) {
                projects.add(projectRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(pId)));
            }
        }

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Projektexport.docx");

        try {
            SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(printer.printProjects(this.prepareProjectExport(projects)));
            saver.save(response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            response.setStatus(500);
            response.sendError(500, "Fehler beim exportieren des Tests aufgetreten");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in @RequestMapping annotation

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
```

Comment: I changed it to `@RequestMapping(value = "/projectWordExport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)` but nothing has changed :(

Comment: The method should return byte[] (byte array) instead of void. Give it a try and tell what happens.

Comment: this might help as well: 
response.body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));

Comment: But I would have to return something then if I change the return type...how?
And how should I fill "inputStream" and which type is it?

Comment: Initialize ByteArrayOutputStream, wrap the file in FileInputStream, fill the baos and return baos.toByteArray()

Comment: I'm stuck at wrapping the file (which file btw? The SaveToZipFile object?) in FileInputStream - any hints on how to do it?

Comment: can you provide implementation of SaveToZipFile ?

Comment: sorry, wasn't aware that this is not a standard class - it's part of the library used to create the word file that I'm trying to be downloaded: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/io/SaveToZipFile.java